# I have following table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Adviceid      Detailid    Orderid    Itemid    Qty

   19140         76841      73036      6194    400.000
   19140         76842      73037       437    500.000
   19140         76843      73038      6194    550.000
   19140         76844          0      6194    100.000
   19141         76845      10001      6194    100.000
   19141         76846      10002      6100    050.000
   19141         76847      10004      6194    050.000
   19142         76848      10006      6100    050.000
   19142         76848      10006      6100    050.000

   19143         76849          0      6101    010.000
   19143         76850          0      6102    005.000
   19143         76851      10007      6101    050.000
   19143         76852      10008      6104    050.000
   19143         76853      10009      6102    050.000
   19143         76854          0      6102    001.000
   19144         76855      25001      6101    050.000
   19144         76856      25001      6102    050.000
   19144         76857          0      6103    050.000
```

I want following output using SQL Query.

```
Adviceid      Detailid    Orderid    Itemid    Qty        AdditionQty

   19140         76841      73036      6194    400.000    100.000
   19140         76842      73037       437    500.000    NULL
   19140         76843      73038      6194    550.000    NULL
   19140         76844          0      6194    100.000    NULL
   19141         76845      10001      6194    100.000    NULL
   19141         76846      10002      6100    050.000    NULL
   19141         76847      10004      6194    050.000    NULL
   19142         76848      10006      6100    100.000    NULL


   19143         76849          0      6101    010.000    NULL
   19143         76850          0      6102    005.000    NULL
   19143         76851      10007      6101    050.000    010.000
   19143         76852      10008      6104    050.000    NULL
   19143         76853      10009      6102    050.000    006.000
   19143         76854          0      6102    001.000    NULL
   19144         76855      25001      6101    050.000    NULL
   19144         76856      25001      6102    050.000    NULL
   19144         76857          0      6103    050.000    NULL
```

I want addition qty according to Adviceid ,Itemid which contain orderid 'O' for example like  Order id = 73036 and also sum of qty if Same order and advice using SQL.

Second Table

Comment: First, do not tag DBMS which you don't use, second, what did you try to so far?

Comment: Can you try to explain this output? Why is this 100 the additionQty for only the first row? Does it appear on Detailid 76841 because that is the lowest value of that column for the same Adviceid?

Comment: If I'm reading this somewhat correct, shouldn't the `AdditionQty` be affected on `OrderID = 73038` as well since it has the same `ItemID` and `AdviceID`?

Comment: Dear User, I want addition qty for order 73036 bcz i want assign addition qty as first order of that advice for this item.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out why you would want something so specific, but this would definitely give you that output:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.qty as additionqty
FROM table t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT adviceid, itemid FROM table WHERE orderid = 0) t2
       ON t1.adviceid = t2.adviceid 
          AND t1.itemid = t2.itemid
          AND t1.orderid = 73036
```

If this should affect any order with the same adviceid and itemid, then remove that last condition on the ON clause... which would make this whole thing make a lot more sense.... but your desired results are your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It works exactly according to your requirements. I have verified it in SSMS.  A screen shot of what I got is also pasted here after the query.

This is really a very complex scenario, but the query below will always work no matter what your data. I have named the table you gave in your question as OrderDetails.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    t.AdviceId
    ,t.DetailId
    ,t.OrderId
    ,t.ItemId
    ,SUM(t.Qty) AS Qty
    ,CASE
        WHEN MIN(t.DetailId) = (SELECT
                    MIN(a.DetailId)
                FROM OrderDetails a
                WHERE t.OrderId <> 0
                AND a.OrderId <> 0
                AND a.AdviceId = t.AdviceId
                AND a.ItemId = t.ItemId) THEN (SELECT 
                    SUM(x.Qty)
                FROM OrderDetails x
                WHERE x.AdviceId = t.AdviceId
                AND x.ItemId = t.ItemId
                AND x.OrderId = 0)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS AdditionQty
FROM OrderDetails t
GROUP BY    t.AdviceId
            ,t.DetailId
            ,t.OrderId
            ,t.ItemId
ORDER BY t.AdviceId,
t.DetailId,
t.OrderId,
t.ItemId;
```

**Screen shot of results of above query in SSMS**

[image: SSMS results of query]

**Data Types of columns in OrderDetails table**

[image: Data Types of Columns in Table]

Comment: I have one confusion in above query,If have First row orderid is '0' and item id is '101'  then 4th  row that order id '1001' and item '101' then the addition qty is not showing in 4th column.Please give some solution.

Comment: In the table OrderDetails that I used AdviceId, DetailId, OrderId, ItemId were   of integer data type and Qty was of decimal type. I am not sure what data types you re using in your table.

Comment: Please check my post since I have added a screen shot of table schema that I used.

Comment: Please check the my question AdviceID with '19143'.  Query is not getting the data for that id.

Comment: I will look into your new data and get back tomorrow.

Comment: Try the new query that I have just posted.